# How to get Python resample function to count UNIQUE values?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like my code to count the unique values, not all of the values together.

DATA SAMPLE:

```
Date        Status        Proj_ID

2021-09-30  Started       p1
2021-09-30  Started       p3
2021-10-19  Started       p4
2021-10-22  Not Started   p2
2021-10-22  Started       p5
```

Output of the current code:

```
Week         #
2021-09-27   2
2021-10-04   0
2021-10-11   0
2021-10-18   3
```

What I want to return:

```
Week         Status       #
2021-09-27   Started      2
2021-10-04   0
2021-10-11   0
2021-10-18   Started      2
             Not Started  1
```

My current code:

```
val3.set_index('Migration/Delete Date', inplace=True)
        
nf_all = val3.resample('W-MON', label='left',closed='left').size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('Status').resample('W-Mon', label='left',closed='left')['Status']\
  .count().swaplevel(0,1).sort_index(level=0).to_frame()
```

Output:

```
                        Status
Date       Status             
2021-09-27 Started           2
2021-10-04 Started           0
2021-10-11 Started           0
2021-10-18 Not Started       1
           Started           2
```

Comment: I get the following error when I run that code: AttributeError: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'normalize'

Comment: Can you check the dtype of the Date column.   `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`  the `df = df.set_index('Date')`.